# Java ClassCastException on getting JSON parsed java object

Tags: java, android, json

Hi guys I have problem in Java. The problem is around parsing JSON with Jackson as I was instructed. My JSON is parsed well, that's not the problem. The problem lies in that I have multiple JSON items in one JSON. I've parsed it like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    List<Unit> unitList = objectMapper.readValue(json,List.class);

    System.out.println("UnitSize " + String.valueOf(unitList.size()));
    System.out.println(unitList.get(0).getUnitEmail());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and at UnitSize it'll tell me that I have precisely 5 objects of Unit type, which is okay, but when I want to get something out of the List it says me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.reddatura.API.HTTPRequest$Unit
```

I've googled it, but nothing relevant. What should be the problem

EDIT:

here is my class snippet:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Unit
{

    @JsonProperty("unitid")
    int unitId;

    @JsonProperty("unitname")
    String unitName;

    @JsonProperty("unitlogo")
    String unitLogo;

    @JsonProperty("unitaddress")
    String unitAddr;
    //other fields, getters setters
    @JsonCreator
    public Unit()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to parse into this model

Comment: You might need to provide some more code. Where exactly are you casting ?

Comment: You can't cast a Unit to a list. You will have to iterate the list and get the objects one by one

Comment: Your List contains LinkedHashMap and not Unit

Comment: Try to see what contain `unitList.get(0)` in the *Debug* environment. See if it contains `Unit` or `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Pedro, how can I achieve it with Jackson?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not casting correctly your json value:

Using `jackson` you could do the following:

```
List<Unit> myUnits = objectMapper.readValue(json, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().
            constructCollectionType(List.class, Unit.class));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but it does not work like this. Gives me error: Unrecognized field "unitid" (Class com.reddatura.API.HTTPRequest), not marked as ignorable when I want to parse it like this :/

Comment: print your json (or at least part of it) and see if the json is arriving correctly

Comment: I'm already printing my JSON and it is valid (ran thru a validator also)

Comment: and the fied unitid is getting value in every jsonobject?

Comment: yep, it is still there, hence it is a must field

Comment: I tried @zozelfelfo's solution and it works for me. I used jackson 2.4.1.1. Maybe you could paste the beginning of the JSON string. Here is the test code I have used http://pastebin.com/bb5ZKXLq Maybe the problem is Android, but I think you should double check the JSON and property mapping.

Comment: unfortunately this gives me the following error:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "unitid" (Class com.reddatura.API.HTTPRequest), not marked as ignorable

Comment: Now I see, the packages are different, I used `com.fasterxml.jackson`and you are using `org.codehaus.jackson` (that's the old one I think). Try using a different jackson lib, or if not possible, then write down the version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            Unit[] unit = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Unit[].class);
            Log.i("TEST", String.valueOf(unit.length)+" ******* "+unit[1].getUnitEmail()+" ******* "+unit[1].getUnitName());

            // or 
            List<Unit> unit1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Unit>>() { });
            Log.i("TEST_1", String.valueOf(unit1.size())+" ****11111*** "+unit1.get(1).getUnitEmail()+" **1111111**** "+unit1.get(1).getUnitName());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this :

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("posts");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    int a = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("a"),
                    String s =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("b"));
            }
```

jsonString is String variable and must be Json syntax